# How to scalling Secondary axis (AxisY2) in Line chart of MS Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I would like to apply scale view option on my chart. I have written the following code which allows me to scale view on AxisY. But not on AxisY2.

```
chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisY2.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
```

I can scale on AxisY but not on AxisY2. can any one knows What I have to change or add in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by myself efforts according to below code.

```
chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisY2.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisY2.ScaleView.Zoom(ScaleMinValue, ScaleMaxValue);
```